# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my function:

```
function tokenizedURL(token, link) {
    url = 'progressions.html';
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({  
            dataType: "json",  
            url: url,  
            async: false,
            data: {idToken: token},  
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 2 || data.status == 0) {
                    alert(data.messageAjax);
                } else if (data.status == 1) {
                    $.each(data.results,function(index, value){
                    //TODO
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

When this function is executed, I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length

pointing to the line with "$.ajax({". But the ajax query is well executed ; each time of the setInterval().

Comment: Check if the returned `data.results` is what you think it is.

Comment: I have juste tested commenting what is under success but the problem is the same.

Comment: EDIT: I didn't clear the cache. With nothing in success, it works. I have to test the data's value. Thanks a lot!